# Django Admin _get_empty_form deprecated?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have been using in implementation of the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10130135/906490) and it works fine on my deployed server in the `django-admin`.  The server is running from an older checkout of django (7cfe8e8fce).  On my local machine, I am running the current checkout (d407164c).  When trying to access that form, I get the error below  and a reference to the `return` line:

```
def _get_empty_form(self, **kwargs):
    return super(ParentInstInlineFormSet, self)._get_empty_form(parent_instance=self.instance)
empty_form = property(_get_empty_form)
```

Error text:

```
'super' object has no attribute '_get_empty_form'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/pmc/admin/pmc_log/reportperiod/add/
Django Version: 1.6.dev20121220194515
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'super' object has no attribute '_get_empty_form'
Exception Location: /software/django-pmc-daily-log/src/pmc_log/pmc_log/forms.py in _get_empty_form, line 18
```

Where did `_get_empty_form` go?  And what is the best way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the private method `_get_empty_form`, I used the `@property` decorator.

```
@property
def get_empty_form(self, **kwargs):
    if self.instance is not None:
        return super(ParentInstInlineFormSet, self).empty_form(parent_instance=self.instance)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `_` at the start of `_get_empty_form` is a pretty good indicator that you shouldn't rely on it being around - it looks like it got removed in favor of using the `empty_form` property.

Try modifying your code to call the `empty_form` property on the parent class.