# Filter inline field in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have the following models:

```
class Provider(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    ...

class Article(models.Model):
    provider = models.ManyToManyField(Provider)
    ...

class Invoice(models.Model):
    provider = models.ForeignKey(Provider)
    ...

class ArticleInvoice(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice)
    ... #qty, status, etc
```

and my admin looks like:

```
class ArticleInvoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ArticleInvoice

class InvoiceAdmin(models.Model):
    inlines = [ArticleInvoiceInline]

admin.site.register(Invoice, InvoiceAdmin)
```

The problem:

When i create an **Invoice**  i have to chose a **Provider**, then add some **ArticleInvoice**s, the **ArticleInvoice** have an **Article** wich has a **Provider**, when i choose the **Article** for the **ArticleInvoice** it shows all the articles.

I would like to apply a filter so i can only create **ArticleInvoice**s in the InvoiceAdmin with **Article**s that have the same **Provider** as the **Invoice**

Comment: you need to override the form and put the logic into the new forms.ModelForm, there are tons of examples on here on how to do that.

Comment: [used this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4236159/6036794)